# Auto Video Height on Columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display two videos with different dimensions in the same row. I'm trying to automatically adjust the height so that there are no weird gaps (like in image 1).

IMAGES: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QK1U.jpg

I've tried out things with flex display but with no success.
My current set-up is:

````
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm block-element-left">
                <video class="rc" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline>
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="video1.mp4">
                </video>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm block-element-right">
                <video class="rc" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline>
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="video2.mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>

<style>
    .block-element-right {
        padding-left: 10px;   
    }

    .block-element-left {
        padding-right: 10px;   
    }

    .rc{
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .col-sm {
    padding: 0%;
    position: relative;
    }
</style>

```
````

Comment: Well the width of your columns would actually have to be determined dynamically, based on the ratios between the two videos ... I don't think this can be done using CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the width and height inside video-tag

```
<div class="col-sm block-element-left">
    <video width="420" height="340" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" 
         playsinline>
             <source  src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I still want the elements to be responsive :/

Comment: Add you class name in vedio tag and remove width form class

Comment: do it works????